# In ExpressionEngine 3, what is the format of the config file to be able to use the Config Service?

Tags: add-on-development, ee3, config

I'm developing an add on for Expression Engine 3, and I can't figure out what the format should be for the config file that will be used from the Config Service. The [Expression Engine documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/services/config.html) says that the config file should be in ./config/ relative to the add on directory, but it has no information on what the format should be.

The docs say that the configuration would be accessed with:

> ee('Config')->get('my_addon:my_config.my_item');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just like the main `user/config/config.php` file.

So in `user/addons/my_addon/config/config.php`:

```
<?php
    $config = array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'baz' => 'foo'
    );
?>
```

Then access your config items like so:

```
$foo = ee('Config')->get('my_addon:foo');
// returns 'bar'
```